# Changing LDAP server in Artifactory 2.3.3.1 has no influence

Tags: ldap, artifactory

We recently change the LDAP server in artifactory 2.3.3.1 from Securoty -> LDAP setting. We changed the LDAP URL to use the new server name.

From - ldap://OLDSERVER.isracard.co.il:389
To -   ldap://NEWSERVER.isracard.co.il:389

But even though, we are still seeing requests when login, in the OLDSERVER. We did a full reboot and it is still directed to the old server.

Are we missing something ? Should we change something else too ?

The "/etc/artifactory.config.latest.xml" also contain the NEWSERVER setting.

We are running on Windows 2008server R2 64bit

Thanks,
Elyahu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutting down the old server forced Artifactory to be directed to the new one.

Thanks all for the support

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory manages a cache for the LDAP authentication but by default, it will have a look to the LDAP after 300 seconds:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Security+with+LDAP

Did you try to create a new LDAP config and to set this new LDAP as the default LDAP (first position)?

Comment: Thanks. We rebooted the Artifactory server so I assume no cache. I also changed the "artifactory.security.authentication.cache.idleTimeSecs" to 0 and still we addressed the OLD one. I haven't tried creating a new LDAP. I'll try to do it later on tonight.